# perl syntax error at wordlist.pl line 11, near ") $fh"

Tags: perl, syntax, operator-keyword, scalar

```
my $fn= "words.txt";
open ($fn), $file;
if (! -e "$fh") $fh="STDIN";
while (<$fn>){;
    my $total_words = @words; #All word count
    my %count;
    $count{$_}++ for @words; # Here are the counts
    my $uniq_words  = scalar keys %count; # Number of uniq words
}
# Print sorted by frequency

print "$_\t$count{$_}" for (sort { $count{$b} <=> $count{$a} } keys %count);

close FILE;
exit 0
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Scalar found where operator expected at wordlist.pl line 8, near ") $fh"
        (Missing operator before $fh?)
syntax error at wordlist.pl line 8, near ") $fh"
Execution of wordlist.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

please help

Answer (score 8):

Perl *always* requires braces around the code after a conditional:

You wrote:

```
if (! -e "$fh") $fh="STDIN";
```

You should write either:

```
if (! -e "$fh") { $fh="STDIN"; }
```

Or:

```
$fh = "STDIN" if ! -e "$fh";
```

Those are syntactically correct.  The code is semantically shot to pieces, though.  To open a file, use:

```
open my $fh, '<', $fn or die "Failed to open $fn";
```

And always use `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.  Perl experts use them to ensure they've not made silly mistakes.  Novices should do the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
open ($fn), $file;
```

Remove the parentheses here.

The first argument is the filehandle, and the second is the filename.  You're using `$fn` as both the filename and filehandle, whereas `$file` is never defined.

```
if (! -e "$fh") $fh="STDIN";
```

You can't leave off the braces around a block like this.  I'm also not sure what `$fh` is supposed to be since you never use it again.

You seem confused about Perl's syntax.  How are you learning Perl?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you got confused between file name `$file` and file handle `$fh`

Try changing your first three lines to

```
my $file= "words.txt";
if (! -e $file) {
  my $fh = *STDIN;
} else {
  open my $fh, '<', $file;
}
```

And it seems there is typo in `$fn`. Shouldn't it be `$fh` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of `open` is incorrect.  The modern way of using it with a three argument call is typically:

```
open my $fh, '<', <file name> or die $!;
```

You specify a new file handle object as the first argument, not the file name.  You also do not need to open a file to check if it exists.  So instead of doing that just do something along the lines of:

```
my $file = 'words.txt';
if (! -e $file) {
  print "$file does not exist\n";
}
else {
 # open your file here and remember to close it
}
```

Then just use the special diamond operator `<>` to operate on `STDIN` if it does not exist.